# Reverse a list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have inserted the EventData EntityList into a normal List and now I want to reverse it.
But it gives the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'"

```
List<Entities.Notification> ProgramList = EventData.ToList();
ListViewEvents.DataSource = ProgramList.Reverse();
ListViewEvents.DataBind();
```

How do I reverse this list? Is it possible to directly reverse the EntityList as well?

Comment: If you want the most efficient way, add it to the stack and then take it off. The first item on the stack is the last off.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reverse does the reversal in place and does not return anything. Instead do:

```
List<Entities.Notification> ProgramList = EventData.ToList();
ProgramList.Reverse();
ListViewEvents.DataSource = ProgramList;
ListViewEvents.DataBind();
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment to the original question instead of an answer.  You're correct, but it's not complete enough to be an answer.

Comment: @Maurice Reeves - Updated for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

The reverse method does not return a new `List`.  Call it, then set the datasource.

```
List<Entities.Notification> ProgramList = EventData.ToList();
ProgramList.Reverse();
ListViewEvents.DataSource = ProgramList;
ListViewEvents.DataBind();
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect. `ListView.DataBind` does not return anything.

Comment: @Romoku, You are correct, I did not read the code thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is choosing the method `List<T>.Reverse()` instead of the Linq extension method `Enumerable.Reverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T>)`.

Since `List<T>.Reverse()` modifies the list by reversing the elements in-place rather than returning a new list, you can either just call that as a separate step:

```
List<Entities.Notification> ProgramList = EventData.ToList();
ProgramList.Reverse();
ListViewEvents.DataSource = ProgramList;
ListViewEvents.DataBind();
```

or

```
List<Entities.Notification> ProgramList = EventData.ToList().Reverse();
ListViewEvents.DataSource = ProgramList;
ListViewEvents.DataBind();
```

or you can call `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()` to bind to the extension method instead:

```
List<Entities.Notification> ProgramList = EventData.AsEnumerable();
ListViewEvents.DataSource = ProgramList.Reverse(); // returns a new IEnumerable
ListViewEvents.DataBind();
```

As a side note, the extension method may perform better that `List<T>.Reverse` since it returns an iterator that traverses the list in reverse order rather than physically reversing the order of items in the list.